# linux common files between two folders

Tags: linux

Hello i have 2 directories both of them contains trees of directories and files. If it is possible, i need a script that verify common files between directories and if he find a common file i need to delete it in DIR2 and make link to DIR1.

example:

- DIR1 includes dir abc1 , abc2, abc3 and abc1 contains file a.txt
- DIR2 includes dir abc1 , abc4, and abc4 contains file a.txt
- Script should delete a.txt in DIR2/abc4 and make a link to DIR1/abc/a.txt

This script would be preferable to be in bash, awk, sed or perl.

Thanks!

#### Example file structure:

```
$ mkdir -- DIR1/ DIR1/abc1/ DIR1/abc2/ DIR1/abc3/ DIR2/ DIR2/abc1/ DIR2/abc4/
✔

$ touch -- DIR1/abc3/a.txt DIR2/abc4/a.txt
✔

$ tree
.
├── DIR1
│   ├── abc1
│   ├── abc2
│   └── abc3
│       └── a.txt
└── DIR2
    ├── abc1
    └── abc4
        └── a.txt

7 directories, 2 files
✔
```

Comment: Are you asking someone to write this for you? Or are you looking for pointers on how to write it yourself?

Answer (score 8):

There is no reason to write a script file, there are commands to do this without scripting.

The command `diff` will **show** you the differences:

```
 diff -r dir1/ dir2/
```

(`-r` = Recursively compare any subdirectories found, [see the Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff)) will print the list of the files which are located **only** in either directory.

If you also want to check whether files with the same name are also identical in content, then you should use

```
diff --brief -r dir1/ dir2/
```

(`--brief` = Output only whether files differ).

If you want to see the differences also for files which exist in **only one** directory, treating their counterparts as empty, you may use

```
diff --brief -Nr dir1/ dir2/
```

(`-N` = Treat absent files as empty).

If you want to **carry out** the operation, the command

```
cp -Rnl dir1/ dir2/
```

will do it for you. Notice that `-R` = copy directories recursively (again [from the Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp)), while `-n` = do not overwrite an existing file.

Comment: Note: He wants to create links, not fully copy the files. I was assuming he meant softlink, but quite possibly hardlinks would work for him (as long as both directories are in the same filesystem). So the copy command should be:
`cp -R -n -l dir1/ dir2/`

Comment: @user2121874 Agreed, I changed the post as per your suggestion. Thx.

Comment: I hope you don't mind. I made an edit to your answer to include the single filesystem limitation of `cp -l`. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

```
comm -12 <(ls folder1 | sort) <(ls folder2 | sort)
```

`comm` prints comparison result of two files. `-12` tells it to suppress unique lines in file 1 and file 2. i.e print only common lines. `<(...)` helps to make the command execution available as a file, substitution. Inside the substitutions, list the contents of the folders, then sort alphabetically.

That's it. Could be put in a script to find for all subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this trivially in bash. The command you are looking for to do the comparisons is `md5sum` or `diff`.

For example here is a script that just compares the  md5sums of two files specified on the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_A="$1"
FILE_B="$2"

if [ "`md5sum $FILE_A | awk '{print $1}'`" == "`md5sum $FILE_B | awk '{print $1}'`" ] ; then
    echo "Same File"
else
    echo "Files Differ"
fi
```

To walk the directory tree you need to use recursion. Here is an example script I wrote a long time ago to rename all files with spaces in the filename to use a underscore instead of a space.

```
#!/bin/bash

rename 's/\ /_/g' ./*
currentdir=`pwd`

### for all files and directories in the current directory.
for filename in `ls` ; do
    ### if "filename" is a directory but not a softlink
    if [ -d $filename ] && ! [ -h $filename ] ; then
        cd "$filename"
        $0 ### This causes the script to call itself. Recursion!
        cd "$currentdir"
    fi
done
```

Then to create links to files between the directories use `ln -s dir1/File1 dir2/`.

Comment: This does not answer the OP: he is comparing two directory trees, which may differ even though all files on both trees are identical, since there may be an extra file (or more) in one tree which is missing in the other.

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of that. I just gave him the inner piece that he would use to compare the files. I left it for him to wrap that inner part in a loop and loop over each file. The question was essentially "Will you write my script for me?", my answer was "No, but here is the non-trivial bit."

Comment: I disagree, this is not the difficult bit at all.  The difficult bit is going thru the directory tree without a script, and keeping it simple; otherwise, `find` will do it  just fine.

Comment: Well, the OP **wants** a script. I have always found walking directory trees to be trivial and require very little thought to get right. Recursion makes it trivial! Perhaps I should include an example of recursion...

Answer (score 0):

There is a command called [`tree`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm) that will output the directory structure.

You could pipe this to a text file then do a comparison on it from there.